# Multiple OR conditions in while loop in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am trying to put multiple OR conditions in my WHILE loop so that unless my "decision" variable is equal to "1" or "2", it will continue looping. However, even when I am entering "1" or "2", it still loops.

```
cout << "Would you like to add or subtract these numbers?"
<< endl
<< "(1) for addition" 
<< endl
<< "(2) for subtraction"
<< endl
<< "Select one: ";
cin >> decision;

while ((decision != 1) || (decision != 2))
    {
        cout << "Please pick (1) for addition or (2) for subtraction: ";
        cin >> decision;
    }

    if (decision == 1)
    {
        cout << firstNum << " + " << secondNum << " = " << firstNum + secondNum;
    }
    else if (decision == 2)
    {
        cout << firstNum << " - " << secondNum << " = " << firstNum - secondNum;
    }
```

Individually the conditions work i.e.

```
while (decision != 1)
```

or

```
while (decision != 2)
```

But not when together. Am I using OR operator wrong?

I have only just started learning C++ so please bear with me, any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: `while ((decision != 1) || (decision != 2))` would be always true because `decision` can't be 1 and 2 at the same time.

Comment: Can you think of any value for `decision` that would make both `decision != 1` _and_ `decision != 2` `false`?

Comment: I think you need the `&&` operator there

Comment: Or do `!(decision == 1 || decision == 2)`, to more closely match the verbal description "unless my variable is equal to 1 or 2".

Answer (score 0):

That would be `while ((decision != 1) && (decision != 2))`.
But I recommend this way.

```
bool decision_check(int decision) {
    switch (decision) {
    case 1:
        cout << firstNum << " + " << secondNum << " = " << firstNum + secondNum;
        return true;

    case 2:
        cout << firstNum << " - " << secondNum << " = " << firstNum - secondNum;
        return true;

    default:
        cout << "Please pick (1) for addition or (2) for subtraction: ";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use this function in `while`.

Comment: Probably ok for this small program, but in a larger design you wouldn't want to do this because it violates the Single Responsibility Principle and does more than the name of the function claims.